# Python Timer consuming too much cpu

Tags: python, ctypes

Running below sometimes fails to alert after 9 hours and more over it's consuming 30% or more CPU, when I check in Task Manager. If anyone can tweak this it would be great.

```
import time
import ctypes
def timer(hours):
    seconds = hours * 3600
    start = time.time()
    time.clock()
    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < seconds:
     elapsed = time.time() - start
    elapsed = elapsed//60
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"Done "+str(elapsed) + " Hrs",  "Done", 0)
timer(8)
```

Comment: You're running a  loop and performing calculations - why not use Python's [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module? That way you can off-load to a separate thread.

Comment: You have a loop with no sleeping or other delays, so it will check and update those values as fast as the CPU can handle, which is why it is using an entire core of the CPU all the time. Also, if this is all you want to do, why not just use [a preexisting timer like Google's](https://www.google.com/search?q=timer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import time
import ctypes

def timer(hours):
    seconds = hours * 3600
    start = time.time()

    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < seconds:
        # Do something once every minute.
        time.sleep(60)
        elapsed = time.time() - start

    elapsed = elapsed//60

    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"Done "+str(elapsed) + " Hrs",  "Done", 0)

timer(8)
```

The problem is that you don't `sleep()` in your loop, so the loop literally just runs many hundreds to thousands or tens of thousands of times per second, eating CPU. The code above will wait 1 minute before repeating the loop.

If you don't need to do anything at all while waiting on the timer, you can avoid the loop entirely and just `sleep()`:

```
import time
import ctypes

def timer(hours):
    time.sleep(hours * 3600)
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"Done "+str(hours) + " Hrs",  "Done", 0)

timer(8)
```

Comment: But below one fails to run accurately when i close or laptop goes to sleep, how to over come this,



import time
import ctypes

def timer(hours):
    time.sleep(hours * 3600)
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"Done "+str(hours) + " Hrs",  "Done", 0)

timer(8)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this achieve the exact same thing? Since you are not doing anything while looping anyways.

```
import time
import ctypes
def timer(hours):
    start = this.time()
    time.sleep(hours * 3600)
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"Done "+str(hours) + " Hrs",  "Done", 0)
```

Comment: Guess we answered around the same time :)

Comment: Guess so. Somehow I get the feeling that using ctypes here is a bit unnessecery/uninformed choice as well, but I could be wrong..

Comment: Yeah, I don't know much about Windows development, but it seems that this uses the Win32 API directly. Maybe there's a Python module with bindings and a nicer interface, but doesn't seem like a terrible way to do it.

Comment: I had used earlier tk, but it opens a canvas window while displaying the message. If there somehow we could hide window by displaying only message box would be good..thank you Will and Telac